# How do you know your current number of inotify parameters (queued_events, user_watches, user_intances) in Linux?

Tags: linux, inotify

I know how to get/set max values for these parameters with /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_* files, but I want to know what is the current value...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any indication that the kernel exposes that information. You could keep a count on the number of inotify instances and watches in your application (the c++-interface does this for you) but that'd be per process and the max_ parameters are per user.